# Plotting error bars using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, errorbar

I'm sure this is relatively easy, but I can't seem to make it work. I would like to plot this df, with date as the x-axis, gas as the y-axis and std as errorbars using the matplotlib module. I can get it to work using the pandas wrapper, but then I have no idea how to style the errorbars.

Using pandas matplotlib wrapper

I can plot the error bars using the matplotlib pandas wrapper `trip.plot(yerr='std', ax=ax, marker ='D')` But then i'm not sure how to access the error bars to style them like one could in matplotlib using `plt.errorbar()`

Using Matplotlib

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(trip.index, trip.gas, yerr=trip.std)
```

or

```
plt.errorbar(trip.index, trip.gas, yerr=trip.std)
```

The above code throws this error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'instancemethod'`

So basically, what I would like help with is plotting the errorbars using standard matplotlib module rather than the pandas wrapper.

DF ==

```
        date       gas       std
0 2015-11-02  6.805351  7.447903
1 2015-11-03  4.751319  1.847106
2 2015-11-04  2.835403  0.927300
3 2015-11-05  7.291005  2.250171
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`std` is a method on a dataframe, ex `df.std()`.

Use

```
plt.errorbar(trip.index, trip['gas'], yerr=trip['std'])
```

or if you have mpl1.5.0+

```
plt.errorbar(trip.index, 'gas', yerr='std', data=trip)
```

Answer (score 1):

- As pointed out, the primary issue is using the `.` notation to access a column name that mirrors a built-in method. While using `.`  is acceptable, it doesn't always work, and may be confused as calling a method instead of a column.

  - The clearest way to select a subset of columns is with `[]` for a single column, or `[[]]` for multiple columns, as shown in [How do I select a subset of a DataFrame?](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) has the `yerr` parameter, which accepts the column name as a string.
- Also see [How to add error bars on a grouped barplot from a pandas column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70085569/7758804).

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sample dataframe
data = {'date': [date(2015, 11, 2), date(2015, 11, 3), date(2015, 11, 4), date(2015, 11, 5)],
        'gas': [6.805351, 4.751319, 2.835403, 7.291005], 'std': [7.447903, 1.847106, 0.9273, 2.250171]}
trip = pd.DataFrmae(data)

# plot the dataframe with error bars
ax = trip.plot(kind='bar', x='date', y='gas', yerr='std', rot=0)
```

[image]

- [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar.html) and [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) also have the `yerr` parameter.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(trip['date'], trip['gas'], yerr=trip['std'])
```

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar('date', 'gas', yerr='std', data=trip)
```

#### `trip`

```
         date       gas       std
0  2015-11-02  6.805351  7.447903
1  2015-11-03  4.751319  1.847106
2  2015-11-04  2.835403  0.927300
3  2015-11-05  7.291005  2.250171
```