# Line Chart with Custom Confidence Interval in Altair

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science, altair

Suppose i have the data frame below:

[image: Selection_101]

I checked the [documentation](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/line_with_ci.html) but it's only based on a single column.

Reproducible code:

```py
x = np.random.normal(100,5,100)
data = pd.DataFrame(x)
epsilon = 10
data.columns = ['x']
data['lower'] = x - epsilon
data['upper'] = x + epsilon
data
```

I'd actually like to use altair, since i like it's interactivity.

Comment: Does this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562556/plotting-error-bars-matplotlib-using-pandas-data-frame fit to your problem?

Comment: I'd actually like to use Altair to benefit from it's interactivity. I'll edit the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can layer a line and an area chart, usng the `y` and `y2` encodings to specify the range:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.random.normal(100,5,100)
epsilon = 10
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': x,
    'lower': x - epsilon,
    'upper': x + epsilon
}).reset_index()

line = alt.Chart(data).mark_line().encode(
    x='index',
    y='x'
)

band = alt.Chart(data).mark_area(
    opacity=0.5
).encode(
    x='index',
    y='lower',
    y2='upper'
)

band + line
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just adding that you can also use `mark_errorband` instead of `mark_area` for the same result:

```
alt.Chart(data).mark_errorband(
    opacity=0.5
).encode(
    x='index',
    y='lower',
    y2='upper'
)
```

[image]

And if the dataframe looks slightly different and contains the upper and lower bound relative the center value instead of in absolute value, you can instead use `mark_errorband` with the `yError` and `yError2` encodings as per [the second example in this section of the docs](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/marks/errorbar.html#using-error-bars-to-visualize-aggregated-data):

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': x,
    'lower': - epsilon,
    'upper': + epsilon
}).reset_index()

alt.Chart(data).mark_errorband(
    opacity=0.5
).encode(
    x='index',
    y='x',
    yError='lower',
    yError2='upper'
)
```

[image]