# Add legend to custom error band chart in Altair

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, altair

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60654627/4841832) we find a snippet of code to build a layered chart plotting a line and error band around it:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.random.normal(100,5,100)
epsilon = 10
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': x,
    'lower': x - epsilon,
    'upper': x + epsilon
}).reset_index()

line = alt.Chart(data).mark_line().encode(
    x='index',
    y='x'
)

band = alt.Chart(data).mark_area(
    opacity=0.5
).encode(
    x='index',
    y='lower',
    y2='upper'
)

band + line
```

[image]

How could I add a legend to specify that the line corresponds to the median and the area to eg a 90% credence interval?

Comment: There are a few solutions for this discussed in this issue thread https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/984